# How to enable Google Cloud PostgreSQL log_statements to one database role only?

Tags: postgresql, logging, google-cloud-sql, privileges

I'd like to have query logging on for one specific role only. But it doesn't seem to be possible to turn it on with the powers of `cloudsqlsuperuser` role that the default `postgres` user has:

```
postgres=> ALTER ROLE my_log_role SET log_statement = 'all';
ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_statement"
```

Turning `log_statement` on for the entire instance is doable through Cloud SQL tools, but can this be done for select role(s) instead of all of them in a managed PostgreSQL?

Comment: Only superusers can change this setting. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)
check if cloudsqlsuperuser is a superusers running "show is_superuser;"

Answer (score 1):

Only superusers can change this setting. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)
check if cloudsqlsuperuser is a superusers running "show is_superuser;"

Superuser restrictions
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#superuser_restrictions

Comment: Cloud SQL is managed and no superuser permissions available... I guess this would then need to be somehow tuned through Google's APIs, if one is available for this kind of operations. Couldn't find something like this yet.

Comment: You should raise a ticket to CloudSQL support team for this kind of requests.

Comment: As Noohone mentioned you can raise the ticket for CloudSQL support using the URL https://cloud.google.com/support

Answer (score 1):

As Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL is a managed service, the ["`superuser`" access is not provided](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/features#unsupported_features), which is required to run the below command:

```
postgres=> ALTER ROLE my_log_role SET log_statement = 'all';
```

However,

> Although you can't create database users with superuser privileges, you can create database users with the `cloudsqlsuperuser` role which has some of those privileges

If this is a blocker, you may consider hosting PostgreSQL on a Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance, where you will have full control.